# How to extract SOAP header from a WS response using spring-ws and jaxb

Tags: java, spring, jaxb, spring-ws

We're using spring-ws 2.2 on our application to consume web services. We've been happily doing this for quite some time and everything is working fine, except that now I need to access the SOAP header in the response and I just can't find a way to do this.

We are using a WebServiceTemplate (from springs-ws) configured with a Jaxb2Marshaller. The jaxb files are generated from the wsdl using xjc. The header element in my responses look something like this:

```
   <soapenv:Header>
         <v1:ResponseHeader status="OK">
             <v1:description>test</v1:description>
          </v1:ResponseHeader>
   </soapenv:Header>
```

In my java class, the code that parses the response looks like this (I've stripped some irrelevant code):

```
public CalculationData getValues(Integer id) throws IntegrationException {
    WebServiceMessageCallback callback = createCallback(soapAction);

    GetValuesRequest request = toGetValues(id);
    GetValuesResponse response = null;
    try {
        response = (GetValuesResponse) webServiceTemplate.marshalSendAndReceive(request,         callback);
    } catch (SOAPFaultException fault) {
        log.error("Soap fault occurred during getValues " + id);
        throw new IntegrationException(fault);
    }

    CalculationData data = fromGetValues(response);

    return data;
}
```

Please help me find a solution for extracting the information from the SOAP header out of the response. I must be able to parse the status code which is sent as an attribute.

By the way. I also have a ResponseHeader.java jaxb class which has been generated from the schemas.

**Update from final changes:**

This is how my handleResponse method looks like after inlining a ClientInterceptor implementation:

```
@Override
public boolean handleResponse(MessageContext messageContext) throws WebServiceClientException {
    SoapMessage message = (SoapMessage) messageContext.getResponse();
    Iterator<SoapHeaderElement> responseHeaderElements =
            message.getSoapHeader().examineAllHeaderElements();
    SoapHeaderElement header = null;
    if (responseHeaderElements.hasNext()) {
        header = responseHeaderElements.next();
    } else {
        log.error("Error! No ResponseHeader found in response.");
        return false;
    }

    String responseCode = header.getAttributeValue(new QName(STATUS_QNAME));
    responseMsg.put(RESPONSE_MSG_KEY, responseCode);
    return true;
}
```

I tried getting the ResponseHeader element by QName, but that did not seem to work for some reason. However, I only expect to get one element in the soap header anyhow, is this will work fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implement a `ClientInterceptor`, specifically see handleResponse() method.

In order to access the Soap Headers, convert to a SoapMessage

```
public final boolean handleResponse(MessageContext messageContext, Object endpoint) throws Exception {
        QName v1ResponseHeaderQName = null;//todo
        QName statusAttrQName = null;//todo
        SoapMessage message = (SoapMessage) messageContext.getResponse();
        Iterator<SoapHeaderElement> matchingHeaders = message.getSoapHeader().examineHeaderElements(v1ResponseHeaderQName);
        String status = matchingHeaders.next().getAttributeValue(statusAttrQName);
}
```

then call `webServiceTemplate.setInterceptors(..)`

For some further examples of this stuff see `AbstractWsSecurityInterceptor` and its subclasses. Be aware however that those interceptors deal with replacing the request message, you just want to read the response message.

Problem is you are dealing with the raw soap message now so you've lost the nice spring marshalling and need to start dealing with namespaces (QNames) and w3c Dom stuff.

In order for the interceptor to pass the header back to the calling code, you could make the interceptor an anonymous inner class that is setup inside your getValues(...) method.

```
final Map<String,String> headers = new HashMap<>();

template.setInterceptors(new ClientInterceptor[]{new ClientInterceptor() {

        @Override
        public boolean handleRequest(MessageContext messageContext) throws WebServiceClientException {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean handleResponse(MessageContext messageContext) throws WebServiceClientException {
            headers.put("foo", "bar");
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean handleFault(MessageContext messageContext) throws WebServiceClientException {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void afterCompletion(MessageContext messageContext, Exception ex) throws WebServiceClientException {
        }
}});
template.marshalSendAndReceive(....);
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer Dan. I was looking at this approach of using interceptors. The thing is I don't understand how I can access the information extracted during handleResponse in getValues. It might be enough with just returning true or false from the interceptor, but the ideal situation would be if I can put the code for handling the result of the call into getValues. In that method I have the forks for what happens when I get different kinds of errors (or warnings) back in the response and to decide what to return. I also need to use this for more complex operations than the one I show.

Comment: Use an anonymous interceptor setup before you call the template.  I'll add an example

Comment: Hi Dan. This seems like a good solution. I will test this as soon as I finished my current tasks (I postponed this change for a later sprint). I'll get back to you with the results and post them here as soon as I've finished them. Thanks alot for the help!

Comment: I've finished implementing the error handling for my web service client now. Works like a charm! Thanks for the help Dan.

Answer (score 3):

For this use case, the best solution is to use a custom `WebServiceMessageExtractor`, as described here:

http://veithen.github.io/2015/01/03/spring-ws-extracting-soap-headers-from-responses.html

Comment: Yes this does seem better than making the template bound to a particular piece of calling code through the anonymous interceptor. Nice.  Would be better to add your solution here for others to see.

Comment: This seems very promising. I hope I get time to take a better look at this solution and use it instead. It seems to allow making a separate class for the WebServiceExtractor to be used by several services. In my case I have three services which has the exact same response header defined in the WSDL. I want to be able to use the same behavior for extracting header data without duplicating code.